# Excel: repeat values in list A for each value in list B

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 lists, say A and B. I need a third list which has values repeated as below:

[image]

And the output should be one of:

[image]

Or:

[image]

I'm unable to recall what kind of 'product' this is called, but I think it has some name to it.

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+combination+of+two+columns+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: **Option One** --> `=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER("_"&TOCOL(A2:A3&"_"&TOROW(B2:B4)),"_",{1,2}),"_")`  | **Option Two** --> `TOCOL(A2:A3&"_"&TOROW(B2:B4))`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya, thank you so much. Unfortunately, I'm unable to mark your comment as the answer, I'm thinking it's because the question is closed.

Comment: Glad to know that it worked for you .